# Dynamically assign button callback - Python

Tags: python-2.7

So I recently started on Python, I love it. I wanted to create a calculator os my first project, I decided to add the buttons with a loop. But the callback of the button is always the last state of the variable that I would like to pass as the argument for the callback function. Here's my code.

```
def addButtons():
buttons = []

label = ""
num = 0

posX = 4
posY = 1

for i in range(12):

    if (i % 4 < 3):
        num += 1
        label = str(num)
    else:
        label = "Blank"

    if (i % 4 == 0):
        posY += 1

    if (posX < 3):
        posX += 1
    else:
        posX = 0

    buttons.append(
        Button(buttonPanel, text=label, command=lambda: function(i), relief="flat", borderwidth=0, sticky=w, background="#fff", activebackground="#eee"))
    buttons[i].grid(column=posX, row=posY, sticky=N + S + E + W)

    buttonPanel.grid_columnconfigure(posX, weight=1)
    buttonPanel.grid_rowconfigure(posY, weight=1)

    functions.append(label)


def function(obj):  # the button's functions are identified by this function and executed respectively
    print obj
```

So, When I click a button I always get 11 from the console, no matter what button. Is there a way that I can dynamically set the callback parameter?

Thanks for any help
 - Jacob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have is that when you write `lambda: function(i)`, the lambda function doesn't save the current value of `i`. Rather, it only looks it up in the outer namespace when it gets called. That's why you see the last value of `i` in all of your callbacks, since that's the value it had when it was last modified.

You can avoid this problem by binding the name `i` to a specific value in the lambda:

```
lambda i=i: function(i)
```

This is sort of an abuse of default arguments, but it does exactly what you want. The current value of `i` in the outer namespace gets bound as the default value for a different `i` variable in the lambda function's namespace. This happens when the lambda is defined, so it doesn't matter that the outer namespace's `i` changes values later on.

Another way of doing essentially the same thing is to use the `partial` type defined in the `functools` module of the standard library.  It lets you bind some arguments to a function that can be called later. This is most useful when you expect some additional arguments later, but it can be helpful in this situation too. Instead of the lambda, you'd pass `partial(function, i)` as the callback.

Comment: Works to perfection, Thankyou so much!

Comment: I tried using this, but amusingly, got only the first value in the list - I guess the value I was assigning in the inner scope was defaulting back to zero?

Comment: Using partial did the trick, in case it helps anyone.